# Node js shell 'type source' command returns 'source not found'

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, gruntjs

While executing node shell command `type source` it shows source not found, but `type type` is  executed successfully.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you entering this into the Node REPL?

Comment: I'm using 'grunt-shell' for executing bash commands.

Comment: When I run the commands on terminal, it's working fine. But not working with grunt as expected.

Comment: if you could give info how you started your grunt-shell it would help to reproduce your problem. on what os are you running it ?

Comment: I have resolved the issue. Created a new file container all the script and running the file as bash. Thanks to everyone for their help.